# Help in Formula's

Tags: formula, formula-field

I have used this formula

```
IF(LEFT(Full_Name__c,FIND(" ", Full_Name__c))=='',
   Full_Name__c,
   RIGHT(Full_Name__c , LEN(Full_Name__c ) - FIND(" ", Full_Name__c ))+
         " ," +  " " +FirstName 
)
```

Full name - Test Automatic

```
Results would be Test , Automatic
```

But I wanted results as

```
 Test, Automatic
```

Comment: Did you try doing below?
IF( LEFT ( Full_Name__c , FIND(" ", Full_Name__c) ) =='', Full_Name__c, RIGHT(Full_Name__c , LEN(Full_Name__c ) - FIND(" ", Full_Name__c ))+"," +  " " +FirstName ) ?

Comment: No worries, sometimes we all overlook.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `TRIM()` formula to remove any undated extra white space.

TRIM() removes any additional white spaces frok a piece of text, I believe (but cannot fully remember) it should remove double spaces from within a piece of text also.

If you do a Google search for TRIM salesforce formula it will bring up the salesforce documentation on how to use it.